# JLabel is not showing up?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jcomponent

I initially created a `JLabel` object and added it to `JFrame` but the content was not showing up.I found a post on `stackoverflow` using container to display `JLabel` on `JFrame`.I tried that too but even that didn't work.I went through a lot of posts but I couldn't find any solution.The button is being displayed but Jlabel is no where to be seen!

```
Dimension s=new Dimension(400,400);
    JFrame l=new JFrame();
    l.setSize(s);
    l.setResizable(true);
    Dimension s1=new Dimension(100,100);
    Container me=new Container();
    JLabel kingsman=new JLabel ("kingsman");

    me.add(kingsman);
    l.add(me);

    JButton p=new JButton("Goal"); 
    p.setSize(s1);
    l.add(p);
    //l.pack();
    l.setVisible(true);
```

There is one more problem.When I call `pack()` function,`Jframe` is getting reduced to a small window instead of the dimension that I have mentioned.
Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the label does not show up is that the content pane of a `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` as its `LayoutManager`. When you call `l.add(me)` and then `l.add(p)` you are effectively replacing the `Container` instance with the button. Try changing you `Container` to a `JPanel`, add both label and button components to that and then add it to your frame's content pane. Read up on [Layout Managers, too.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html.)

The following example shows a `JPanel` containing a `JLabel` and `JButton` arranged using the `JPanel's` default `LayoutManager` of `FlowLayout`.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.add(new JLabel("A Label"));
    content.add(new JButton("A Button"));

    frame.add(content);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: What happens if I directly add Jlabel to the frame without using container?

Comment: @MathewsMathai Nothing (or more to the point, the same thing), `JFrame` is a container (actually, it has a `JRootPane`, which has a `contentPane` and it adds things to it)

Comment: If you wish to add directly to the frame, you will have to apply some positional constraints. As stated, the `LayoutManager` in use is a `BorderLayout`, so instead of calling `frame.add(label)` and `frame.add(button)` you might do `frame.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH)` and `frame.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTRE)`. From a design point of view I'd suggest using a JPanel with an appropriate `LayoutManager` for your content and then add the panel to the frame.